# How do I use loop statement instead of go to statement

Tags: java, goto

```
 while(true)
    {
  
        switch (...)
        {
            case 1:
                //some code
                break;
            case 2:
                //some code
                break;
        }


        System.out.println("(1)Continue (2)Exit");

   //example:

        int choice = scanner.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1)
            continue; //it should go to switch

        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Exit..."); // should exit
            break;
        }

 
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong num, try it again!"); // should ask choose again until we enter 1 or 2

            //goto example;
        }

    }
```

My problem is: It goes to the beginning of the loop when I choose the wrong number. I want it to go to the part where the choose is asked (int choice = scanner.nextInt();) and asking again. "1" - > switch, "2" - > "exit" , "3" - > ask choice again.

Comment: Put the loop around the bit you want to loop around: if you don't want to go back to the switch, either move the `while` after the switch; or put another loop around the input and if/else.

Comment: You should not need a `goto` statement, ever. As already said: loop over the right thing and then use `break` / `continue` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
    private static void switcher(int key)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case 1:
                //some code
                break;
            case 2:
                //some code
                break;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        switcher(0);//replace with whatever you need
        System.out.println("(1)Continue (2)Exit");
        while(true)
        {
            int choice = sc.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1)
                continue;
            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Exit...");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Wrong num, try it again!");
            }
            switcher(0);//replace with whatever you need
        }
    }
}
```

If you have other requirements, please update your question.

Comment: when i doing like this, it never goes `switch` again. For example in this code when i choose "1" it's looping but it's not going to switch. The thing is "1" -> `switch`, "2" - > exit, "3" - > ask choice again until you enter 1 or 2.

Comment: Code updated. See if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try like the below

```
while(true)
{

    int choice = scanner.nextInt();

    if (choice == 1)
        continue;

    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Exit...");
        break;
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong num, try it again!");
        //goto example;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try doing something like this, maybe a little ugly but I think it will work:

```java
        function get_choice(choice) {
            if (choice == 1) {
                // do something
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                // do something else
            } else {
                // something else
            }
        }
```

and then you just do something like `get_choice(1);`

Answer (score -1):

try this approach:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter your choice :");
            System.out.println("1. Start program");
            System.out.println("2. End   program");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = sc.nextInt();
        } while (choice != 2);
        System.out.println("Exit application :");
    }

}
```